# Peut-on mettre un point d'interrogation après "n'est ce pas, quoique ce soit au milieu d'une phrase?

Tags: ponctuation

Je lis ***L'Ennemie*** d'Irène Nemirovsky.  Dans la quatrième partie, Section 4, Charles (23 ans) a cherché Gabrielle (dont il est amoureux) pour l'amener chez sa mère, Francine (dont il est l'amant réticent) à Biarritz.  Situation assez compliquée, alors. Les émotions de Gabri sont compliqués/ambivalentes.  Elle dit:

> — Mlle Boyer vient avec nous ?

Evidemment elle espère avoir cette 'gouvernante' comme défense contre les désirs de Charles et aussi d'elle-même. Charles répond :

> — Jusqu'à Paris seulement.  Après, n'est ce pas ? c'est inutile.

Est ce qu'on peut mettre un point d'interrogation comme ça ?  Nemirovsky était née Russe, mais éduquée par une gouvernante française et passait beaucoup de sa jeunesse en France.

Pardonnez, s'il vous plait, une question aussi banale. J'ai parcouru l'internet, sans succès.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oui, « N'est-ce pas ? » est une proposition incise.

Une proposition incise est normalement entourée de virgules mais comme elle se termine ici par un point d'interrogation, ce dernier tient lieu de virgule. On ne met jamais de virgule après un point d'interrogation.

Comment: Thank you, Nix, I had not come across the expression 'proposition incise', which is useful.  I think I read it in one of the online entries.  Also, thank you for patiently editing my terrible French.  I would respond in French, but do not want to disgrace myself again.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: @Tuffy You have high standards, obviously you had not set any proofing tools to check the spelling that's all, whereas a native French speaker like myself would do that, hence some of those mistakes. If the most you can complain about are a few spelling mistakes here and there which further wouldn't even show if this were speech, and you have sound sentences and all, I mean that's pretty good already. My point is don't hesitate to comment in French to practice. There was no disgrace. Cheers.